# Calculus Integral sec(x)tan(x) Problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following problem:

$$\int \sec(1-z) \tan(a-z) dz$$

This is the integral trig formula I have:

$$\int \sec ax \tan ax~dx=\dfrac 1 a \sec ax+C$$

I am confused what does $a$  stand for in this problem?

Is it just a $-1$ in front of $z$ or is $a = 1-z$ ?

Also, is substitution needed for this problem?

It would be really helpful if someone could solve this in a step by step manner so I can see.

Comment: $a$ is a coefficient. For your integral, you want to consider $u$ substitution with $u = 1-z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the formula should be used when a is a constant, and x is a variable. Instead, we can use a simple u-substitution (which nmsanta also used, but was a little less clear) with $u=1-z$ and $du=-dz$ to obtain the following integral:

$$\int \text{sec}(1-z)\text{ tan}(1-z)\text{ }dz = -\int \text{sec}(u)\text{ tan}(u)\text{ }du$$

Now that we have transformed it into the form that your formula uses, we can say that in the case of $a=1$ and $x=u$ as well as a negative out in front:

$$-\int \text{sec}(u)\text{ tan}(u)\text{ }du = -\frac{1}{a} \text{sec}(au) + C = -\text{sec}(u) + C$$

Substituting $u=1-z$, you get your solution:

$$\int \text{sec}(1-z)\text{ tan}(1-z)\text{ }dz = \boxed{-\text{sec}(1-z) + C}$$

Answer (score 1):

For your problem $~a=1~$ and here $~x=1-z~$.

**Solution:**$$I={\displaystyle\int}\sec\left(1-z\right)\tan\left(1-z\right)\,\mathrm{d}z$$
putting, $~x=1-z~$, then $~dz=-dx~$
$$I=-{\displaystyle\int}\sec\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-\sec(x)~+~c$$
$$=-\sec(1-z)~+~c$$
$$=-\sec(z-1)~+~c$$where $~c~$ is integrating constant.